# I want to get today's date without time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Currently what I am doing is I am comparing some date say oldDate with today's date

```
             NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];
             NSComparisonResult result = [oldDate compare:dt];
            if (result == NSOrderedAscending)
            { 
              // do something
            }
```

dt gives me today's date with time also. But I want just date and no time. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: A lot of answers on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889164/get-nsdate-today-yesterday-this-week-last-week-this-month-last-month-var http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331129/how-to-determine-if-an-nsdate-is-today

Answer (score 13):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: But I need to compare two dates here, so by this way if I am converting date_String to nsdate, I am getting the time added to it.

Comment: ok,you have first convert date to string as above code and after you compare two string as.... [String_date1 isEqualToString:String_Date2];

Answer (score 4):

To take care about timezones and everything you could do something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)day {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:self];
    return [components day];
}

- (NSInteger)month {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:self];
    return [components month];
}

- (NSInteger)year {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self];
    return [components year];
}
```

Of course you can put it all together in one function just remember to alter `components` accordingly.

**Caveat:**
If you want something to show to the user, use one of the other answers with NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a date formatter to correctly output the date and/or time for an `NSDate` object.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Setting the different `NSDateFormatterStyle` types will yield more or less information as required, i.e.: "Tuesday, 1st January 2013", or "01/02/2013".

Comment: But how to get date from this dateString without the time added to it. Because when I am converting this dateString to date ( dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString) I am getting time added to it yet again

Comment: By setting `[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];` the date formatter will remove the time for you regardless of how you convert the date to a string, or string to a date.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate Date];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Now the string **timeString**  contains the current time in HH:mm:ss format, i.e. 11:26:59

**Whoops Misread the question! this is for time only for date see other answers - might as well leave this here also.**