# Test if NSDatePicker is equal to the current time

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatepicker

I am trying to create code that tests wether the date selected in a UIDatePicker is equal to the current date. I am tying to get it to act as an alarm clock (user selects a time, they press a button, and an alert is displayed when that time is reached). Thanks! Here is my code:

```
#import "AlarmViewController.h"

@interface AlarmViewController ()

@end

@implementation AlarmViewController

NSDate *selectedDate;
NSDate *now;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    now = [NSDate date];
[_setDatePicker setDate:now animated:YES];
}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)setAlarm:(id)sender {
selectedDate = [_setDatePicker date];
[self checkDate];

}
-(void)checkDate{
if(selectedDate == now){
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The date and time you selected   
is:    %@", selectedDate];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"time selected" message:message   
delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
@end
```

Comment: Use `isEqualToDate` instead of "==", but I guess, you want to determine if it's today, so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331129/how-to-determine-if-an-nsdate-is-today

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! How do I make that if statement always be testing if the dates are equal, as opposed to just testing it once?

Comment: What do you mean "always testing"?

Comment: That the if statement is always testing the arguments

Comment: Since everytime you press the button, you go do `checkDate`, I don't see what's your issue.

Comment: Are you talking about continuously checking to see if the date equals the selected date in order to trigger an alarm? Also, I believe the UIDatePicker defaults to the current date/time, that is, it sets the date to: `[NSDate date];`

Comment: ajfigueroa ya that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Do you have an answer?