# How to determine if NSDate is today

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am an experienced Unix C programmer, relatively new to Objective C and OS X. I want to determine if an NSDate is today.  My method is copied from a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331129/how-to-determine-if-an-nsdate-is-today):

```
    + (BOOL)        isToday:(NSDate *)aDate {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
    components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:aDate];
    NSDate *otherDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    BOOL isToday = [today isEqualToDate:otherDate];
    return isToday;
}
```

The code compiles, but generated deprecation warnings for each NSInteger NSxxxCalendarUnit.  A quick search shows the updated constants of the form NSCalendarUnixxxx.

How do I use the new constants?  I tried replacing the line:

```
components = [cal components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:aDate];
```

With

```
components = [cal component:(NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:aDate];
```

But I get conversion warnings.  Do I need to explicitly cast this OR'd constant?  The new constants are of type NSUInteger, NSCalendarUnit.  The "components:" argument seems to be expecting NSCalendarUnit, so I'm not sure what I am missing...

And, yes, I know that iOS8 and OS X 10.10 include new calendar functions (described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/Foundation.html)), such as isDateInToday:, but I am looking for an iOS 7 compatible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have written the name of the `components:` parameter as `component:`. Those are not the same thing, as you should know if you are an "experienced C programmer" - just as two variables called `thing` and `things` are not the same.

If you correct that error, then your change to modernize the names of the components will compile just fine, without any warnings:

```
+ (BOOL) isToday:(NSDate *)aDate {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
    components = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:aDate];
    NSDate *otherDate = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
    BOOL isToday = [today isEqualToDate:otherDate];
    return isToday;
}
```

Comment: However, I don't guarantee that that will run in iOS 7, because I don't know when terms like `NSCalendarUnitEra` replaced terms like `NSEraCalendarUnit`. If it won't, then you will just have to live with the deprecation warnings.

Comment: Changes in enum element names are purely a compile time thing. It can't cause a problem when running on iOS 7, because the values are identical.

Comment: @KenThomases Right, I was thinking there could be a problem, but once it compiles for iOS 8 it's all just numbers as far as iOS 7 is concerned. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Matt Thank you! I am visually impaired,  I missed the "component" vs. "components" change.  I need to pay more attention to where Xcode code completion stops, to identify these similarly named methods.

Comment: @SDGary It is a huge problem no matter how well you can see! But unfortunately it makes a major difference. :(