# How to display alert once a day

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to figure out how I can make an alert popup once the user has reached their goal. However, I only want it to show once a day after it's been triggered. Apologies in advance. if my logic is off with tackling this issue.

```
// Check to see if hydration goal has been reached
if (waterCups >= dailyHydrationGoal) {

   // User has reached goal

    if (alert has not been fired yet today) {
        // alert pop up you reached your goal!
    }
}
```

How would I go about ensuring it only launches once per day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`isDateInToday:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1417149-isdateintoday?language=objc) method to check whether the given date is in “today.”

```
NSDate *lastAlertDate = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastAlertDate"];
if(![[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:lastAlertDate]){
     //Show alert
     NSDate *today= [NSDate date];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:today forKey:@"lastAlertDate"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a persistence store? (NSUserDefaults, core data etc...)

You can store a time stamp (NSDate) of the last time an alert was shown then check if the last time it was shown is today.  [How to determine if an NSDate is today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331129/how-to-determine-if-an-nsdate-is-today)

If an alert has not been shown today, pop an alert and record a new time stamp.